# sbt 1.4.4 with IntelliJ: Extracting structure failed

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am getting a rather strange error when trying to use the IntelliJ built-in sbt-compiler to open projects with `sbt` 1.4.0 or higher:

[image: Extracting structure failed]

Everything works fine for projects configured to use `sbt` 1.3.x or lower. In this example, I was trying to open the [ScalablyTyped Demo](https://github.com/ScalablyTyped/Demos) project. The same keeps happening with other projects as well. I upgraded my IntelliJ to the Community 2020.2 version and the Scala plugin to version 2020.2.49, but to no avail.

Compiling the projects with the built-in `sbt` shell works, so it seems to be a problem of IntelliJ itself. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 2:

This seems to be causing the error, but I have yarn installed and can use it in a cli, so that is rather surprising:

```
* Welcome to ScalablyTyped demos!
*
* For documentation see https://scalablytyped.org .
*
* Note that the first time you import/compile the projects it'll take a while for the dependencies to build
*
[info] set current project to demos-master (in build file:/C:/Users/baierlf/Downloads/Demos-master/Demos-master/)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last electron / externalNpm' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last electron / ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] (electron / externalNpm) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "yarn" (in directory "C:\Users\baierlf\Downloads\Demos-master\Demos-master\electron"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann     die angegebene Datei nicht finden
[error] (electron / ssExtractDependencies) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "yarn" (in directory "C:\Users\baierlf\Downloads\Demos-master\Demos-master\electron"): CreateProcess error=2, Das     System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 01.12.2020 15:42:43
[info] shutting down sbt server
```

Translation:

German: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

English: The system is unable to locate the file

Edit 3:

I can run the yarn command, when doing it manually:

[image: yarn]

Comment: Can you please share your `build.sbt`? If you click with your mouse on the top level failure (Demos-master: failed) you'll see more details about what failed.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I have updated the question with the error message now (thanks! I never tried to click on the topmost element). The build.sbt is here: https://github.com/ScalablyTyped/Demos/blob/master/build.sbt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue about that in github: [java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "yarn"](https://github.com/ScalablyTyped/SlinkyDemos/issues/12).

The suggestion there is to add yarn to the path in the environment variables.

If that doesn't help, you can try, as a workaround, to set the path to `yarn` [here](https://github.com/ScalablyTyped/SlinkyDemos/blob/master/build.sbt#L134) manually. In case someone will read this in the future, and the code will change, you should change the line with the content:

```
Process("yarn", baseDirectory.value).!
```